# Thymeleaf Exception Parsing Document - Css Template

Tags: html, css, spring, thymeleaf

I am using the a kube css framework (https://imperavi.com/kube/css/buttons/ ). But i can not implement the framework into the my project.

```
<button type="black" small outline>Button</button>
```

When i am trying to use button like this, it occurs this exception : 

 **Attribute name "small" associated with an element type "button" must be followed by the ' = ' character.**
Is there anyway to use this button with small and outline attributes.

Comment: Does `small="small" outline="outline"` work?

Comment: It works thanks but is this the right way ?

Comment: You probably want to ensure the button uses the CSS classes, similar to the examples here: http://imperavi.com/kube/docs/buttons/#h-small so you would add a button and style it using thymeleaf th:class like: `<button th:class="button primary small">Button</button>`.

Answer (score 0):

It is common problem with thymeleaf to parse html 5 markup. Here is the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28624768/thymeleaf-strict-html-parsing-issue).