# Thymeleaf SAXParseException: not displaying HTML page

Tags: java, html, spring, thymeleaf

I want to display my index.html file that is located in my resources/templates folder but I get a strange error that doesnt seem to make sense. Iam using Thymeleaf dependency and ModelAndView display the index.html file.

***This is my controller:***

```
@GetMapping("/")
@ResponseBody
public ModelAndView getEvaluatePage() {
    ModelAndView mv=new ModelAndView();
    mv.setViewName("index");
    return mv;
}
```

***This is my index.html:***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/html">
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet"
              href="/webjars/bootstrap/3.3.7-1/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
        <script src="/webjars/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="/webjars/bootstrap/3.3.7-1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function submitFileForm() {
                var fd = new FormData(document.getElementById("fileinfo"));
                $("#file-upload-info").fadeIn( "slow" );
                $('span #watson-expression').text('');
                $.ajax({
                    url: "/evaluate",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: fd,
                    processData: false,
                    contentType: false
                }).done(function(data) {
                    console.log(data.measurments);

                    var items = "";
                    $.each(data.measurments, function(i, item) {
                        items = items + item.name + '</br>'
                        items = items + 'f1: ' + item.f1 + '</br>'
                        items = items + 'recall: ' + item.precison + '</br>'
                        items = items + 'precision: ' + item.recall + '</br>'
                        items = items + '###</br>'

                    });

                    $('#score').html(items);
                    $('#file-upload-info').fadeOut( function() {
                        $('#file-upload-success').fadeIn( "slow" ).delay(4000).fadeOut( "slow" );
                    });
                    $('#watson-expression').text('');
                }).fail(function() { 
                    $('#file-upload-info').fadeOut( function() {
                        $('#file-upload-error').fadeIn( "slow" ).delay(4000).fadeOut( "slow" );
                    });
                    $('#watson-expression').text('');
                });

                return false;
            }
        </script>


        <meta charset="UTF-8" />

    </head>
    <body>

        <div class="container">

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="page-header">
                        <h1><span id="watson-expression"></span> Watson Validation Service - <small>Validering av testdata</small></h1>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <div class="panel-heading">Ladda upp valideringsfil till Watson</div>
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <label class="control-label">Välj testdata</label>
                                <form method="POST" id="fileinfo" enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="return submitFileForm();">
                                    <input id="input" name="evaluationfiles" type="file" class="file file-loading" data-allowed-file-extensions='["zip"]'>
                                    <input type="submit" value="Ladda upp" />
                                </form>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-12 alert alert-info" role="alert" style="display: none;"  id="file-upload-info"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-file" aria-hidden="true"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh glyphicon-refresh-animate"></span> Överlämnar valideringsdata till Watson...</span></div>
                            <div class="col-md-12 alert alert-success" role="alert" style="display: none;" id="file-upload-success"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up" aria-hidden="true">Watson tackar för valideringsfilen</span></div>
                            <div class="col-md-12 alert" role="alert" style="display: none;" id="file-upload-error"> Watson kunde inte ta emot valideringsfilen</span></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <div class="panel-heading"> Score</div>
                        <div class="panel-body" id="score">

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

***Error i get is:***

```
2018-01-02 08:53:35.647 ERROR 29940 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine             : [THYMELEAF][http-nio-8080-exec-1] Exception processing template "index": Exception parsing document: template="index", line 24 - column 56
2018-01-02 08:53:35.650 ERROR 29940 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Exception parsing document: template="index", line 24 - column 56] with root cause

org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The element type "script" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</script>".
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:203) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.fatalError(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:177) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:400) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:327) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLScanner.reportFatalError(XMLScanner.java:1472) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanEndElement(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1749) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2967) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:602) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:505) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:841) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:770) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1213) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:643) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:327) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.xmlsax.AbstractNonValidatingSAXTemplateParser.doParse(AbstractNonValidatingSAXTemplateParser.java:209) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.xmlsax.AbstractNonValidatingSAXTemplateParser.parseTemplateUsingPool(AbstractNonValidatingSAXTemplateParser.java:134) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.xmlsax.AbstractNonValidatingSAXTemplateParser.parseTemplate(AbstractNonValidatingSAXTemplateParser.java:116) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateRepository.getTemplate(TemplateRepository.java:278) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1104) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1060) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1011) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.spring4.view.ThymeleafView.renderFragment(ThymeleafView.java:335) ~[thymeleaf-spring4-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.spring4.view.ThymeleafView.render(ThymeleafView.java:190) ~[thymeleaf-spring4-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1286) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1041) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:984) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceUrlEncodingFilter.doFilter(ResourceUrlEncodingFilter.java:59) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197) ~[spring-web-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1459) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_144]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_144]
```

I have tried to look at the script tag and even if I remove them entirely it complains about Another tag that is not closed properly, even if they are. I dont Think the problem lies in the tags it has to be something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thymeleaf engine cannot parse the `index.html` document, because `<script>` tag is not closed, by default Thymeleaf require developer to close **all** html tags in the view document. So solution is to just do what the exception message says.

For more details [this might be helpful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3558119/are-non-void-self-closing-tags-valid-in-html5), and also that [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28624768/thymeleaf-strict-html-parsing-issue).

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I managed to solve it using your second link

Answer (score 1):

Using the link

[Thymeleaf - Strict HTML parsing issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28624768/thymeleaf-strict-html-parsing-issue)

I followed the answer and used LEGACYHTML5 for Thymeleaf as solution by adding the following lines to the application.properties file

```
spring.thymeleaf.mode=LEGACYHTML5
spring.thymeleaf.cache=false
```

And the required dependency:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sourceforge.nekohtml</groupId>
        <artifactId>nekohtml</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.21</version>
    </dependency>
```